# How to run Junits locally using Google Cloud Storage service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage (GCS) in my GAE application. For that I wrote some JUnits to test functionality that is dependent on the GCS.
How to configure Junits for GCS ?

Earlier I used Blobstore using Google FileService API. But FileService API is deprecated, so that I moved to GCS and using GcsService API. For Blobstore Junits I used -

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper blobStoreHelper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig());
```

It worked for me successfully. Here what I have to do to run the GCS Junits successfully ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special configuration required to setup GCS for JUnit test cases. Here I have some logical issues in my code, so that I was unable to run JUnits using GCS. After resolving those logical issues JUnit test cases are working fine with GCS.